# How do I unit test an apache camel route with no output endpoint?

Tags: java, apache-camel

How would I create a junit test for this route if there's not an output path?

```
from("{{input.files.tab}}")
        .routeId(IdRoute)
        .autoStartup(isAllowed(IdRoute))
        .onCompletion()
        .onCompleteOnly()
        .modeBeforeConsumer()
        .setHeader(COMPLETE_ONLY, constant(COMPLETE_ONLY))
        .process(new ELFTracingProcessor(internationalRocPricingBalancing, tracer));
```

Answer (score 2):

Camel is very powerful and flexible, and as a result there are myriad ways to do this. Here are a few:

1. You could test the result of whatever `ELFTracingProcessor` does.
2. You could add a `to("mock:xyz")` as the last step and use Camel's [Mock Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/mock-component.html) facilities to test that the Mock was invoked.
3. Personally the previous option doesn't bother me at all. Cars come with dipsticks for a reason. But if you don't want to see the call to the Mock component, you can use [AdviceWith](https://camel.apache.org/manual/advice-with.html) to add a call to the Mock component:

```java
AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, "myRouteId", builder -> {
    builder.weaveById("myProcessorId").after().to("mock:xyz");
});
```